# Библиотеки для работы с usb в java

Tags: java, usb

Подскажите пожалуйста библиотеки для работы с usb а точнее получение и отправка данных по usb.

Видел usb4java, пробовал, но мне выдавало ошибку ([тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/675696/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82-usb-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2-java-se-usb4java)).

может ещё есть библиотеки с примерами?

Comment: Ссылка не работает. Ошибку от `usb4java`, думаю, всё же можно исправить.

Comment: @L'Esperanza поправил ссылку. Не знаю. гуглил. ничего не дало.